# Is there a way to automatically post to a Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I would like to be able to add blog posts to a Facebook group via a service like RSS Graphiti. I know this is possible for Facebook pages, but is this possible for Facebook groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of targets in RSS Graffiti contains both groups and pages that I'm an admin of.  (Though I haven't tried whether it actually works.)

Comment: I will give that a try. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I have Tried RSS Grafiti -- hyptothetically posting to a group works but I haven't been able to get it to work.

I tested [dlvr.it](http://dlvr.it/) posting to a Facebook group, and it seems to work just fine. Note that it too uses RSS.

Comment: it works for groups you are admin of