# Is there any way to make an automatic post with image to a Facebook group you aren't admin of?

Tags: facebook, twitter, facebook-pages, facebook-groups, instagram

Note: I already know this question: [Is there a way to automatically post to a Facebook group?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28481/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-post-to-a-facebook-group)

The answer there is right (I've been using it for a long time) for groups you are admin of. But what I want to do is, either posts to Facebook pages, Twitter, or Instagram, with images to be posted in Facebook Groups I'm not an admin of. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how this was written this seems to be asking about an app that bypasses the [`user_managed_groups`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/group/photos#pubperms) permission.

Since you already possibly know this will not work, the overall answer to this question is that there is no way to do this natively without a custom application/script (which is outside the scope of this site).

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by "custom apps"? isnt IFTTT a custom app and it has a tag here?

Comment: You're not asking about IFTTT. You're asking about Facebook, to respond with the answer IFTTT means this question now becomes your original post title (which will make this question off-topic).

Comment: Custom app here refers to anyway to circumvent the native way to attempt this. This might mean using a first party access token or using an application like IFTTT. The former is a programming problem (out of scope) the latter is an app recommendation (also out of scope)

Comment: So questions which asks if you can do something in a social network  with an undefined app arent allowed? unless you specify which app you want for doing so? am I getting it right?

Comment: Correct, the original aim of the site was to be an extension or alternative support to understand the usage of an app for a basic to advanced power users. Over the years, it was decided that methods requiring programming or app recommendations were not consistent and often became obsolete (in some cases it provided unnecessary marketing and spam) You can see more in meta about this meta.webapps.stackexchange.com